# Tensor product and valence of a tensor?

Tags: tensor-products, tensors, multilinear-algebra

Given a vector space $V$, its dual vector space $V^{*}$ and a tensor $\mathbf{T}$:

$\mathbf{T} \in \underbrace{V \otimes\dots\otimes V}_{n\text{ copies}}\otimes \underbrace{V^{*}\otimes\dots\otimes V^{*}}_{m\text{ copies}}$

Then what is the valence $(p, q)$ of the tensor where:

- $p$ denotes the number of contravariant indices
- $q$ denotes the number of covariant indices

Is it $(n, m)$ ($n$-times contravariant and $m$-times covariant) or $(m, n)$ ($m$-times contravariant and $n$-times covariant) ?

Extra question: could someone explain me why in the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor) $n$ and $m$ are swapped between the "[as multilinear maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor#As_multilinear_maps)" part and the "[using tensor products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor#Using_tensor_products)" part?

Comment: does it help http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:FourfacesofBilinaearmaps.PNG ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Over the reals, as an example, for a tensor $T$ to be used as a map you must consider mapping 
$$T:
\underbrace{V^*\times...\times V^*}_{n\text{ copies}}
\times 
\underbrace{V\times...\times V}_{m\text{ copies}}\to{\Bbb{R}}$$ 
via 
$$T(f_1,...,f_n,x_1,...,x_m)=$$
$$=T^{i_1\dots i_n}_{j_1\dots j_m}\; {e}_{i_1}\otimes\cdots\otimes{e}_{i_n}\otimes {\varepsilon}^{j_1}\otimes\cdots\otimes{\varepsilon}^{j_m}(f_1,...,f_n,x_1,...,x_m)$$ $$=T^{i_1\dots i_n}_{j_1\dots j_m}f_1(e_{i_1})\cdots f_n(e_{i_n}){\varepsilon}^{j_1}(x_1)\cdots{\varepsilon}^{j_m}(x_m),$$
where some arguments $f_i\in V^*$ and $x_j\in V$.
It is routine to check multi-linearity.

Observe that evaluating at basics covectors and vectors we get: 
$$T({\varepsilon}^{k_1},...,{\varepsilon}^{k_n},e_{r_1},...,e_{r_m})=T^{k_1\dots k_n}_{r_1\dots r_m},$$
since ${\varepsilon}^{\alpha}(e_{\beta})={\delta^{\alpha}}_{\beta}$.

Valence and type are the same.